# how to extract intercept and slope from a plot for large number of variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, coefficients

I am trying to extract intercepts and slopes for 500 variables from a qplot. The code I am using:

```
qplot(gd, nd, data = test, colour = factor(ENT)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
```

Could someone help me extract the intercept and slope for each regression line (500 lines/variables) as plotted in the attached figure.

[image]

Comment: here is it on flickr: https://www.flickr.com/photos/132350438@N04/?

Answer (score 6):

`ggplot` will draw the graph, but you extract the coefficients (Intercepts and Slopes) from the `lm()` objects. One way to do the latter is to use dplyr's `group_by()` and `do()` functions. See ?do

I'm using the mtcars data frame here.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, colour = factor(cyl))) +
   geom_point() +
   geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)

mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    do({
      mod = lm(disp ~ mpg, data = .)
      data.frame(Intercept = coef(mod)[1],
                 Slope = coef(mod)[2])
    })
```

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
Groups: cyl

  cyl Intercept      Slope
1   4  233.0674  -4.797961
2   6  125.1225   2.947487
3   8  560.8703 -13.759624
```

Comment: Hi all, I am using some logistic model where I can extract slope, and inflection point. But I would like to extract y-resonses at a certain position on the logistic fit curve. For example, in the figure attached.

Comment: @Ravi,  you should ask a new question.  Also, figures don't attach to comments.

Comment: Hi Sandy..Yes I have asked this question separately here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30676509/extracting-defined-response-points-in-logistic-fits

Answer (score 4):

How about using the `lmList` function, which is designed for computing linear regressions across multiple groups?

```
library("nlme")
coef(lmList(nd~gd|ENT , data = test))
```